# How to detect a particular word in a string using C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, string-matching

I need to write an if statement using C# code which will detect if the word "any" exists in the string:

```
string source ="is there any way to figure this out";
```

Comment: You should use of Regex Expressions to match `any` word in a string

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a string exists in another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848337/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-exists-in-another-string)

Answer (score 3):

```
String stringSource = "is there any way to figure this out";
String valueToCheck = "any";

if (stringSource.Contains(valueToCheck)) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you really want to match the word (and not things like "anyone"), you can use regular expressions:

```
string source = "is there any way to figure this out";
string match = @"\bany\b";
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(source, match);
```

You can also do case-insensitive match.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach combining and extending the answers of [IllidanS4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31866063/4302070) and [smoggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31863863/4302070):

```
public bool IsMatch(string inputSource, string valueToFind, bool matchWordOnly)
{
    var regexMatch = matchWordOnly ? string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", valueToFind) : valueToFind;
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(inputSource, regexMatch);
}
```

You can now do stuff like:

```
var source = "is there any way to figure this out";
var value = "any";
var isWordDetected = IsMatch(source, value, true); //returns true, correct
```

Notes:

- if `matchWordOnly` is set to `true`, the function will return `true` for `"any way"` and `false` for `"anyway"`
- if `matchWordOnly` is set to `false`, the function will return `true` for both `"any way"` and `"anyway"`. This is logical as in order for "any" in `"any way"` to be a word, it needs to be a part of the string in the first place. `\B` (the negation of [`\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in the regular expression) can be added to the mix to match non-words only but I do not find it necessary based on your requirements.

Comment: Also you can use *Regex.Escape* to prevent regex patterns being passed to the method, if needed. Though I cannot think of any word that is also a regex pattern...