# Looking for an regular expression for "${sometext}"

Tags: c#, regex

What I found out using this
`"\\${(.*?)\\}`.

So I tried:
`new Regex(@"\\$\\${(.*?)\\}");`

But this seems not to work, whats the problem here ?

Comment: What's wrong with [string.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You have a rare problem: **Just one *dollar* too much...** The second `$` is not needed... Try `new Regex(@"\\$\\{(.*?)\\}");`

Comment: Specifically read the comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5848360/542251)

Comment: @Liam I think OP needs to match strings dynamically... I suspect OP wants to get the matched group in a later step...

Comment: @Liam I don't know the text between **${}**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `new Regex(@"\${(.*?)}");`

Let's analyze yours:

```
(@"\\$\\${(.*?)\\}");
   ^^^^^^      ^^^
   ||||||      |||-- Your don't need to double your slashes in a literal string.
     \  |        |       
      \ |        |
       \|--------|-- You have 2 "$" and you just want one
                 |
                 |-- You don't need to escape "{" since it doesn't enclose digits
                     and can't be interpreted as a length attribute.
```

Comment: Presumably the error then is that the OPs attempt was escaping slashes inside a string literal?