# Change textcolor of a row in a datagridview if a cell contains part of text c#

Tags: c#

How is it possible to change a whole row forecolor, if a cell in that row contains some text?

I have a code like this but it only changes the color of the cell that contains the exact word.

```
private void constringview_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString() == "838")
        {
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.BlueViolet;
        }

    }
```

I would like to color the whole row, if a cell contains a part of a word

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a string exists in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848337/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-exists-in-another-string)

Comment: Can't get it to work in the datagridview :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the row, by getting Row index form DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs as below

```
private void constringview_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString() == "838")
        {    
           dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.BlueViolet;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Found out that if I changed the IF value to "e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString().Contains("CGMFW")" my contain issue was solved also =D