# if URL contains, then execute

Tags: c#, url

I have the following code:

```
else if (url == $"{Link}" + "?rerror=2")
{
    // do something here
}
```

The user inputs `"Link"`, then the program navigates to that link. I then want the program to determine if the url contains "?rerror=2" on the end of the url, to do something else.

Comment: Have you tried `else if (url.Contains("?rerror=2"))` or `else if (url.EndsWith("?rerror=2"))`?

Comment: thank you, I finally got it! I did else if (driver.Url.Contains("?rerror=2")) and it worked. I apperciate the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a string exists in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848337/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-exists-in-another-string)

Comment: use `string.EndsWith(string)`