# Finding a string within another string using C#

Tags: c#, string

How do I find out if one of my strings occurs in the other in C#?

For example, there are 2 strings:
string 1= "The red umbrella";
string 2= "red";
How would I find out if string 2 appears in string 1 or not?

Comment: [`string.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

you can use String Contains I guess. pretty sure there is similar question have been asked before [How can I check if a string exists in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848337/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-exists-in-another-string)

example :

```
 if (stringValue.Contains(anotherStringValue))
{  
// Do Something // 
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this:

```
public static bool CheckString(string str1, string str2)
{   
    if (str1.Contains(str2))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call the function:

```
CheckString("The red umbrella", "red") => true
```

Comment: `Contains()` returns a boolean.  Why write another function that doesn't change the only logic of the method it calls?

Comment: @Erik Philips yes that's right. just have to call str1.Contains(str2)