# How I can check if substring contain another substring c#

Tags: c#

//the word skill it's a substring for two string i want to compare based it

```
string first = "skill.Name";
string second = "jobskillRelation";
first.Contains(second);
```

Comment: split, loop, compare.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848337/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-exists-in-another-string

Comment: Could you clarify the question? What's the output you're trying to get for these two strings?

Comment: If you are looking for [longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), there's no built in utility to compute it. You can either implement it yourself (see wiki link above), or search for a library.

Comment: please reformulate the question, we can't possibly understand it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use **Longest Common Substring** code provided [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_Common_Substring), the C# version is like this:

```
    public static string lcs(string a, string b)
    {
        var lengths = new int[a.Length, b.Length];
        int greatestLength = 0;
        string output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
            {
                if (a[i] == b[j])
                {
                    lengths[i, j] = i == 0 || j == 0 ? 1 : lengths[i - 1, j - 1] + 1;
                    if (lengths[i, j] > greatestLength)
                    {
                        greatestLength = lengths[i, j];
                        output = a.Substring(i - greatestLength + 1, greatestLength);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lengths[i, j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

so the usage will be:

```
var LCS = lcs(first,second)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to compare two string to see if both contain a certain keyword, this may help.

```
    Boolean compare(string first, string second, string keyword)
    {
        if (first.Contains(keyword) && second.Contains(keyword))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```